# C - Strings are giving me errors

Tags: c, gcc

So I am writing a simple code to print out each symbol in my string. When compiling it, it gives me an error tough that I do not understand:

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char my_string[50];
    int i, n;
    printf("Type in a string please : ");
    scanf("%s", &my_string);
    n = strlen(my_string);
    for (i = 0;i < n; i++) {
        printf("%c",my_string[i]);
    }

}
```

The error it gives:

```
gcc yl2.c -o Yl2
yl2.c: In function ‘main’:
yl2.c:9:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%s", &my_string);
  ^
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: `yl2.c:9:2: warning:...` It's a *warning*, not an *error*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf("%s", &my_string);` there should not be a `&`.

Since you have declared `char my_string[50];` my_string as character array which is of type `char *` which is expecting in `scanf()` as the warning states.

Just use, `scanf("%s", my_string);`. Base address of the array as argument is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s", &my_string);` should be `scanf("%s", my_string);`

`my_string` is an array, which decays to a pointer when you type it out without [ ].
If you type `&my_string`, you get an array pointer, which is strictly speaking not the same thing. That's why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 2):

`&my_string` is a pointer to `my_string` i.e. a `‘char (*)[50]’`

You can either use

```
scanf("%s", &my_string[0]);
```

or more conventionally

```
 scanf("%s", my_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove & sign in scan, it will work
Also no need to use string.h here